# How do I decode the Numbers in the url

Tags: python

I want to crawl this url in python, using post requests，
http://www.huibaizhi.com/Data/Majors/GetByCode?code=f65c370436e35d43，
I know this string 'f65c370436e35d43' is going to be a number 130101,but how is it encode? Because now I already have the number,I need to encode it,and initiate a request

Comment: i bet `f65c370436e35d43` is going to be a number `42`, can you prove me wrong?

Comment: thanks a lot, I found it was encrypted by JS,AES encryption and encryption results into hexadecimal

Comment: encryption usually has an encryption key, did you really expect us to find the encryption key? congratulations on finding the answer, though =)

Comment: I'm trying to find the key,thank you!